# Relation between transition rate and hazard function?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

1. For a stochastic process $X$ with continuous time and discrete state
   space, if $\forall i$ in the state space $$ P(X_{t+h}=i \mid X_t=i) = 1
       - r_{ii} h + o(h) $$ and for $\forall j \neq i$, $$ P(X_{t+h}=j \mid X_t=i) = r_{ij} h + o(h). $$ where the transition rates $r_{ij}$ and
   $r_{ii}$ are independent of $t$. How is the hazard function of "the
   sojourn time at state $i$" random variable related to the transition
   rates?
2. If the transition rates $r_{ij}$ and $r_{ii}$ are piecewise constant
   over $t\leq t_0$ and $t> t_0$, what is the distribution of "the
   sojourn time at state $i$"? Is it called piecewise exponential
   distribution?

Thanks!

Comment: My comment to your other question answers this, no?

Comment: @Did: Yes, it does. thanks! In my first part here, I am confused about the concept of hazard function and the concept of transition rate.

Comment: Seems like a mere matter of definition checking. All in all, I fail to see a question here...

Comment: @Did: Does the transition rate equal to the value of the hazard function for the sojourn time at zero? The hazard function generalizes the transition rate from sojourn time taking zero to sojourn time taking any nonnegative value?

Comment: When I mentioned "definition checking", I was suggesting that you could easily check them yourself.